# Tilted text for x-axis using css/sass

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions

How to tilt the text in the x-axis as shown in the image. I tried with transform but I'm unable to tilt it.

I've the text inside the span like this:

`<span className="o-display-month">{value.Date}</span>`[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element must **not** be inline. Then you can use the rotate for the transform with a negative value `transform:rotate(-XXdeg);`

```css
.times{list-style:none;padding:0}
.times li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:1em;
  transform:rotate(-40deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="times">
  <li>1 pm</li>
  <li>2 pm</li>
  <li>3 pm</li>
  <li>4 pm</li>
  <li>5 pm</li>
  <li>6 pm</li>
  <li>7 pm</li>
  <li>8 pm</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow..Cool !! I didn't think of negative values.Thank you.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal keep in mind that a `-40deg` is the same as `320deg`

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property transform like so: `transform: rotate(30deg)`
Also consider you would need to asign inline-block property to your span tags

Answer (score 0):

you can make the span display:inline-block and then rotate it..it will work

```
.o-display-month{
  display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since span is an inline element, **transform property won't work for inline elements**. you have to change the display property to inline-block or block. then You can use rotate property.

```
.rotated {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* Equal to rotateZ(45deg) */
}
```